# sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

Tags: python, regex

I am using a regex and I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tokennet.py", line 825, in <module>
    RunIt(ContentToRun,Content[0])
  File "tokennet.py", line 401, in RunIt
     if re.search(r'\b'+word+r'\b', str1) and re.search(r'\b'+otherWord+r'\b',   str1) and word != otherWord:
   File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py",     line 142, in search
     return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

I've looked around, and it seems this error is associated with `*`, but not sure why I'm getting it. What do I have to do to `str1` to stop getting it? `str1` is one line in a massive text file, and when I print `str1` to see what line in particular is bugging, it looks like a normal line...

Comment: What's your input? What's the content of variable word?

Comment: `print "SEARCHING",repr(string1),"for",word,otherWord` returns `SEARCHING u'chapter 8 chromosome function cell cycle dynamic ' for dynamic +end`

Comment: did you try `re.escape(word)` ?

Comment: Hmmm It must have something to do with +end

Comment: Thank you, it appears to work. just to double check: I have put   `if re.search(r'\b'+re.escape(word)+r'\b', str1) and re.search(r'\b'+re.escape(otherWord)+r'\b', str1) and word != otherWord:`, is that what you meant?

Comment: yep, the same because the variable may contain some regex meta characters. By using `re.escape(variable)`, it escapes any regex meta character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to use `re.escape(word)`, since your variable `word` may contain any regex special characters. I think the error came because of special characters present inside the variable. By using `re.escape(variable-name)`, it escapes any special characters present inside the variable.

```
if re.search(r'\b'+re.escape(word)+r'\b', str1) and re.search(r'\b'+re.escape(otherWord)+r'\b', str1) and word != otherWord:
```